# How do I checkout a working copy with folders but not files?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to create a working copy with all child folders but without files in it?
 My repository is very big, I only need the empty directory structure to be created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the --depth switch to check out an empty directory:

```
svn co --depth empty <URL>
```

Then you can do a `svn update --depth empty <folder>` for each folder you are interested in.

For documentation of the feature "sparse directories" see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).